# The scanf() function for age doesn't work

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;

    printf("How old are you?");
    scanf("\d", &age);

    printf("\nYou are %d years old", age);

    return 0;
}
```

I think the ampersand in the `scanf()` function doesn't work. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You are calling `scanf` incorrectly, it should be `scanf("%d", &age);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just wrote the wrong format of `scanf()` function.
there should be `%d` instead of `\d` because for taking input inside `scanf()` you have to use %.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int age;

  printf("How old are you?");
  scanf("%d", &age); // change **%** instead of **\**

  printf("\nYou are %d years old", age);

  return 0;
}
```